# What good Java template engine should have?

Tags: java

Im starting to write my own template engine for Java. It will be primarily intended to Spring Framework. I usually use Freemarker, but I know template engines such as Java Server Pages, or Thymeleaf. Im doing it only for fun purposes and to develop my programming skills. I have a few assumptions to my template engine, but I want to ask you what features (in your opinion) good template engine should have?

For now my template:

- Deals with null values. Instead of throwing an Exception, which screams, that value is not present - just leave variable declaration in parsed HTML (like Angular).
- Use HTML5 tags only, so future vendors wouldn't have to install special plugins or editors to deal with strange file extensions (such as Freemarker ftl files).

I'm grateful for all hints.

Comment: My hint, for what it's worth: study other templating engines, look at the features they have, and decide which features you want to include in your own templating engine.

Comment: Thymeleaf is disgusting and I have no idea at all why it's heavily promoted in most spring resources. Try out Jade4J, it doesn't get more comfortable than that I guess: https://github.com/neuland/jade4j

Comment: @G.Spansky So, did anything ever come out of this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few that immediately come to my mind:

- Localization. There should be an easy way to translate all the strings into different languages without setting up some crazy TemplateMessageResolverProviderFactory beans.
- Different content types. You seem to be thinking "text/html" only for now, but I often want to send plain text email messages too. So there should be a way to return "text/plain", i.e. without using any HTML tags in the template.
- Variables. There should be an easy way to embed variables into the localized strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will include that points into my plan.